# Cannot insert into ComboBox

Tags: java, combobox, vaadin

I'm developing an application with vaadin, and now i have this trouble. I have a form composed from many vaadin component (TextField,DateField,ComboBox etc). One of these ComboBox should has to manage both insert value and selection values. I would want insert  a value that does not appear in the list contained in the comboBox. (something like temporary value).

I tried something about:

```
 ComboBox c = new ComboBox()
 c.setTextInputAllowed(true);
```

but it doesn't work like i want.

How can i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To allow user input you have to set `c.setNewItemsAllowed(true);`

The identifier of an item added by the user will be a String object identical to the caption of the item.

Note: Adding new items may not be possible if the Select is bound to an external Container that does not allow adding new items.

Comment: Thanks, it work but i added also c.setImmediate(true)

Answer (score 1):

```
c.setNewItemsAllowed(true);
c.addItem("apple");
c.setValue("apple");
```

These [demos](http://demo.vaadin.com/sampler-for-vaadin6#ComboBoxPlain) also contain source code.